# Delete LF from file using C#

Tags: c#, ssis, newline, lf

I have to make a script in C# to delete 'LF' from a file.

The structure of the file like this :

```
line1 'CR''LF'
line2 'CR''LF'
line3 'LF'
some_text_of_line_3 'CR''LF'
```

I want to have this :

```
line1 'CR'
line2 'CR'
line3 some_text_of_line_3 'CR'
```

Thank you !

Comment: Please note you haven’t asked a question. What is the actual problem? Opening files? Reading characters? Comparing them to specific one? Writing them?

Comment: Right. I have nothing of it actually, i'm a beginner in C#.

Comment: Wait is it actually ASCII character 10 Line Feed? Or the string text `'LF'`?

Comment: It's the ASCII character 10 Line Feed, but it's a csv file.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not that *large* (i.e. we can read it into memory):

```
 using System.IO;

 ...

 String path = @"c:\MyFile.txt";

 // Read file, remove LF (which is "\n")
 string text = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace("\n", ""); 

 // Write text back
 File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Comment: I don't explain that it's a csv file, not txt..sorry my bad

Comment: @Thomas: well, *csv* is a *text* file, that's why nothing should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Regex expression for this:

```
string myFile= File.ReadAllText(@"c:\FileName.txt");
myFile= Regex.Replace(myFile, @"LF", "AnythingYouwantHere");
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\FileName.txt", myFile);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't explain that it's a csv file, not txt..sorry my bad

Comment: @SmailxCoder.  No, he wants to replace the line feed character (ASCII: 10 c#:  \n) from the end of lines.  These are print control characters.  This is different than the character literal 'LF'.

Comment: @JazzmanJim Okay i understand now, at first i didn't understand what he really wants, thats why i gave him an answer equivalent to what i did understand, Thank you

Comment: @SmailxCoder.  No problem.  This is the type of issue us old coders ran into in the 80's and 90's.  :)